# can you apply media queries in the <noscript/> tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries, noscript

Hey so im trying to display a message to the user if javascript is disabled using the noscript html tag. the message simply just asks them to re-enable javascript in their browser settings.

however i want to also include a media query so that the message is responsive with the width and height of the screen. i want to know is it possible to use media querys when javascript is disabled or are media queries reliant on javascript?

Comment: No, media queries are CSS stuff and unrelated to javascript. They work surely in a noscript area.

Comment: It would be faster to try it out than to write this question.

Answer (score 1):

No, Media queries are not dependent on JavaScript. You can use media query as you wish in stylesheet or  tag (External/Internal).

Answer (score 1):

Media queries can only be applied in CSS, since they are not mainly based with JavaScript. You would have to use the `<style></style>` tags for this.